# Convergence proofs: why is it necessary to prove specifically for $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In most proofs of sequence convergence in real analysis (like [here](http://planetmath.org/node/42134) and [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mdc/old/153/notes4.pdf)) in order to prove that, for example 
$$
a_n + b_n \to_n a+b
$$
or 
$$
a_n b_n \to_n ab
$$
when $a_n \to_n a $ and $b_n \to_n b$ often it is often taken that $|a_n -a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, which follows from the fact that (for a different $n$ of course) $|a_n -a|<\epsilon$. Or, for the product proof that $|a_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+a)}$. Once again, for a different $n$. After some algebra it is shown that the desirable quantity, say $a_n b_n$ is within an $\epsilon$ from $a+b$.

Well here's my confusion (and question): why not just prove that (in the first case)
$$
|a_n +b_n -(a+b)| <2 \epsilon
$$
and this would imply that of course for some other $n$ it is less than $\epsilon$. And the same with other proofs. In short: why, if we are allowed to play around with discrepancies from the limit of other sequences, we absolutely must show that the desired one is strictly less than $\epsilon$ away?

Comment: Personally, I think many proofs in textbooks (and even research papers) would be more reader friendly if they didn't go through these convolutions to get exactly $\epsilon$ at the end. For me at least, it's much easier to have the proof proceed in a "natural discovery method" and then when something is eventually shown to be less than $f(\epsilon)$ for some function $f,$ deal with whether $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$ implies $f(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0.$ That said, I must confess that I often don't do this myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar to the difference between leaving a solution un-simplified.  It is clear that answers of $5/10$ and answers of $1/2$ are equivalent but we generally write solutions as simplified as possible.

When it comes to these proofs, an answer showing $|a_n +b_n -(a+b)| < \frac{23486}{777}\epsilon^{239\pi}$ could be considered un-simplified. It is usually a small matter to resolve and should be done if possible.

If you find that $|a_n +b_n -(a+b)| < 2\epsilon_0^{2}$ you can say "take $\epsilon = 2\epsilon_0^2$" or "take $\epsilon_0 = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$" which then shows that $|a_n +b_n -(a+b)| < \epsilon.$ It should be clear that resolution of this matter is almost trivial.

Authors of books and papers will write their proofs so that this is unnecessary simply because it produces the cleanest proofs and that is always an advantage when writing anything. Any student should have the skills to take their proofs and modify them to fit this criteria.

Comment: OK, so as Daniel Littlewood pointed out, this is a matter of aesthetics and succinctness, right?

Comment: @Alex Yes. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of looking at this.

Some people say "if the target is $\epsilon$, then we haven't got a proof unless we achieve $\epsilon$, and nothing greater will do."

Others do the equivalent of proving that if we can show our expression is less than $A\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, where $A$ is a constant independent of $n$, then we can also show that it is less than $\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. This result can then be used to avoid having to deal with potentially troublesome constants.

You can do it either way, but for the second way, you do need to have the proof in your back pocket - because that is what allows you to avoid the additional steps you need to take in the first case.

Comment: Although I usually prove things with $C\varepsilon$, I recognize that some students can't see that this is a good proof. Their definition has $< \varepsilon$, why should we be happy to have $< 3\varepsilon$? This might be wrong!

Answer (score 2):

It's just aesthetics, really. You are right that if, say, $|(a_{n}+b_{n})-(a+b)|$ is twice an arbitrarily small quantity, then it is an arbitrarily small quantity itself.

Comment: 'It's just aesthetics, really' are you quite sure? I've never seen this point before.

Comment: @Alex Yes, there is nothing more to it. I have seen professors give proofs where an expression was bounded by an ugly expression containing $\epsilon$s and constants, and that was the end of the proof.

Comment: In fact, in some textbooks (I have seen it in _Fourier Analysis: An Introduction_ by E.M. Stein and R. Shakarchi) don't bother with making the final quantity exactly $\epsilon$, as long as it's a constant multiple of it.